# What options do exist now to implement UTF8 in Ruby and RoR?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, internationalization

Following the development of Ruby very closely I learned that detailed character encoding is implemented in Ruby 1.9. My question for now is: How may Ruby be used at the moment to talk to a database that stores all data in UTF8?

Background: I am involved in a new project where Ruby/RoR is at least an option. But the project needs to rely on an internationalized character set (it's spread over many countries), preferably UTF8.

So how do you deal with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.8 works fine with UTF-8 strings for basic operations with the strings. Depending on your application's need, some operations will either not work or not work as expected.

Eg:

1) The size of strings will give you bytes, not characters since the mult-byte support is not there yet. But do you need to know the size of your strings in characters?

2) No splitting a string at a character boundary. But do you need this? Etc.

3) Sorting order will be funky if sorted in Ruby. The suggestion of using the db to sort is a good idea.

etc.

Re poster's comment about sorting data after reading from db: As noted, results will probably not match users' expectations. So the solution is to sort on  the db. And it will usually be faster, anyhow--databases are designed to sort data.

Summary: My Ruby 1.8.6 RoR app works fine with international Unicode characters processed and stored as UTF-8 on modern browsers. Right to left languages work fine too. Main issues: be sure that your db and all web pages are set to use UTF-8. If you already have some data in your db, then you'll need to go through a conversion process to change it to UTF-8.

Regards,

Larry

Answer (score 1):

"Unicode ahoy! While Rails has always been able to store and display unicode with no beef, it’s been a little more complicated to truncate, reverse, or get the exact length of a UTF-8 string. You needed to fool around with KCODE yourself and while plenty of people made it work, it wasn’t as plug’n’play easy as you could have hoped (or perhaps even expected).

So since Ruby won’t be multibyte-aware until this time next year, Rails 1.2 introduces ActiveSupport::Multibyte for working with Unicode strings. Call the chars method on your string to start working with characters instead of bytes." [Click Here for more](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2007/1/19/rails-1-2-rest-admiration-http-lovefest-and-utf-8-celebrations)

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tested it, the character-encodings library (currently in alpha) adds methods to the String class to handle UTF-8 and others. Its page on RubyForge is [here](http://rubyforge.org/projects/char-encodings/). It is designed for Ruby 1.8.

It is my experience, however, that, using Ruby 1.8, if you store data in your database as UTF-8, Ruby will not get in the way as long as your character encoding in the HTTP header is UTF-8. It may not be able to operate on the strings, but it won't break anything. Example:

```
file.txt:
¡Hola! ¿Como estás? Leí el artículo. ¡Fue muy excellente!
```

Pardon my poor Spanish; it was the best example of Unicode I could come up with.

```
in irb:
str = File.read("file.txt")
   => "\302\241Hola! \302\277Como est\303\241s? Le\303\255 el art\303\255culo. \302\241Fue muy excellente!\n"
str += "Foo is equal to bar."
   => "\302\241Hola! \302\277Como est\303\241s? Le\303\255 el art\303\255culo. \302\241Fue muy excellente!\nFoo is equal to bar."
str = "    " + str + "    "
   => "    \302\241Hola! \302\277Como est\303\241s? Le\303\255 el art\303\255culo. \302\241Fue muy excellente!\nFoo is equal to bar.    "
str.strip
   => "\302\241Hola! \302\277Como est\303\241s? Le\303\255 el art\303\255culo. \302\241Fue muy excellente!\nFoo is equal to bar."
```

Basically, it will just treat the UTF-8 as ASCII with odd characters in it. It will not sort lexigraphically if the code points are out of order; however, it will sort by code point. Example:

```
"\302" <=> "\301"
   => -1
```

How much are you planning on operating on the data in the Rails app, anyway? Most sorting etc. is usually done by your database engine.

Comment: Sorry to say but as stated in the question I am not interested in Ruby 1.9 or Ruby 2.0 atm. AN reading / writing to a database might be okay, too, but what about, lets say, sorting these data afterwards?

Comment: Would doing the sort in the SQL query help?