# Ruby String accent error: More than meet the eyes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, character-encoding

I'm having a real trouble to get accents right, and I believe this may happen to most Latin languages, in my case, portuguese

I have a string that come as parameter and I must get the first letter and upcase it! That should be trivial in ruby, but here is the catch:

```
s1 = 'alow'; s1.size #=> 4
s2 = 'álow'; s2.size #=> 5

s1[0,1] #=> "a"
s2[0,1] #=> "\303"

s1[0,1].upcase #=> 'A'
s2[0,1].upcase #=> '\303' !!!

s1[0,1].upcase + s1[1,100] #=> "Alow" OK
s2[0,1].upcase + s2[1,100] #=> "álow" NOT OK
```

I'd like to make it generic, Any help?

**[EDIT]**
I found that Rails Strings can be cast to Multibytes as seen in class ../active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte.rb, just using:

```
s2.mb_chars[0,1].upcase.to_s #=> "Á"
```

Still, @nsdk approach is easier to use =)

Comment: what you found about mb_chars is your solution. You can also require Multibyte from Active Support 3 in your non-Rails applications (I do it all the time in Sinatra apps and system scripts). You should answer your own question and mark it as a correct answer, not @nsdk's.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`s1.sub /^(.)/ do |char| char.upcase end`

Comment: This doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 5):

The character `á` is not represented a single byte in UTF-8 strings, but the two-byte sequence `C3`, `A1`. So when you slice `[0,1]` from the string you get only the first byte of it, `\C3` or `\303`, which you can't meaningfully `upcase`.

Ruby 1.8 doesn't do Unicode, so you're going to be fighting against byte strings and having lots of problems like this trying to write internationally-aware applications in it. See eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160016/what-options-do-exist-now-to-implement-utf8-in-ruby-and-ror) for some background. Ruby 1.9 finally fixes this (although I dislike its approach).

Comment: This is a good explanation of the problem, but you don't provide a solution (except switch to 1.9).